# AJAX call inside plugin class not triggering

Tags: ajax

I have read other questions regarding the same issue but nothing seems to help in my case. Maybe someone sees something in my code that I cannot see?

I created a plugin with a class, then I have an AJAX call that triggers when I click on a HTML element on the page. All seems to work, except that it doesn't enter the callback inside the plugin.

**plugin.php**

```
class BSPFPluginClass {
  protected $nonce = 'mynonce';

  public function __construct() {
    /** other actions here ... */
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'myinit' ) );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_myajaxcall', array( $this, 'myajaxcall' ) ); // executed when logged in
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_myajaxcall', array( $this, 'bspf_ajax_voting' ) ); // executed when logged out
  }

  public function myinit() {
    // Register the script
    wp_register_script( 'plugin-js', plugins_url( 'js/plugin.js', __FILE__ ), array() );

    if (is_page('somepage')) {
      // Enqueued script with localized data.
      wp_enqueue_script( 'plugin-js' );
      // Localize the script with new data
      wp_localize_script( 'plugin-js', 'plugin_ajax', [
        'ajax_url' => plugins_url( 'plugin.php', __FILE__ ), 
        'nonce'    => wp_create_nonce( $this->nonce ),
      ]);
    }
  }

  public function myajaxcall() {
    check_ajax_referer( $this->nonce );
    if (true) {
      echo 'Yes it works!';
    }
    else {
      echo 'No it does not work!';
    }
    wp_die(); // stop executing script
  }
}
```

Then, **js/plugin.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".myclass").click(function() {
    $.post(plugin_ajax.ajax_url, {
      _ajax_nonce: plugin_ajax.nonce,
      action: 'myajaxcall'
    }, function(response) {
      console.log('SUCCESS: '+response);
    }).done(function() {
      console.log('DONE');
    }).fail(function() {
      console.log('ERROR');
    }).always(function() {
      console.log('ALWAYS');
    });
  });
});
```

When I hit the HTML element with the trigger class everything goes well and I get the following on the console:

```
SUCCESS: 
DONE
ALWAYS
```

So it is like everything is correct, except is not entering the action 'myajaxcall'.

Any leads?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The `ajax_url` should be `admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )` and not `plugins_url( 'plugin.php', __FILE__ )`

Comment: @Laxmana you should post that as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ajax_url` should be `admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )` and not `plugins_url( 'plugin.php', __FILE__ )` when you localize your js variables.

Comment: Thank you @Laxmana , actually, the AJAX is not for an admin page but rather a public page, so I don't see why I would need to add the `admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )`

Comment: No. `admin-ajax.php` is a WordPress Core file that handles Ajax Requests. It's inside wp-admin folder. WordPress acts like a controller that handles Ajax requests and executes the appropriate action of the request. I suggest reading more about Ajax in WordPress [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

Comment: It doesn't matter if the Ajax call is being made from a public page or a admin page or even a different site. All Ajax calls should be made at `admin-ajax.php` for your hooked action to be executed.

Comment: Thank you @Laxmana, this is the right answer. It works like a charm. I hadn't read that article you shared and it really helped me. Thank you!

Comment: @Dani You are welcome! If you are satisfied with the answer please accept it.